# spring boot: create multiple context for the same application-context.xml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I need to create multiple context for the same application context.xml file and each context use its own application.properties.

How to do it using spring boot ?

I have 3 clients who have the same behaviour but each one with specific details declared into client-application.properties.

So i use also spring integration and the flow will be reused for each client .
I need to launch 3 clients in the same time and each one with its own application.properties. And i use xml for that.

Comment: Take a look at [spring profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). How do you want to manage your contexts - as xml or as java classes?

Comment: Ehm why, what is the use case for this?

Comment: i updated my question. Please help me to find a solution, it is very urgent

Comment: Just start the application 3 times. Specifying an additional config file for each. Don't try to hack around, work with the framework.

Comment: is it a safe solution if i  start the application 3 times (i speak about performance)?  because the application belongs to a group and they require to have a common  application launched on the same machine  for all affiliates, each affiliate has its own configuration but they have the same behaviour.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I appreciate your solution  so no doubt about performance beacause i use spring integration also ?

Comment: Why would that be different then creating a single main launching the same thing 3 times? You are loading the same configuration and thus the same application 3 times already. Basically you are already loading your application 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this... I have a single project, and inside of it are three application.properties (or the number you need)

in application.properties, i specify general parameters

[image]

and in each application-.properties i specify specific environment properties, e.g., the port in production:

[image]

And the port for my dev profile:

[image]

In order to use them check the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) that Ivaylo recommended

...A small example:

[image]

In this case, the application will boot on the port showed in the different .properties files.

You can specify the profile like: mvn spring:boot run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Comment: i use xml to configure context.xml, so for the <property placeholder location=?/>  what should i write and i note that all aplication.properties are externalized

Comment: Something like this: https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml